# React-native, "Native module cannot be null"

Tags: react-native

I just upgrade React-native from 0.28 to 0.30, and get this error:

"Native module cannot be null".

The problem seem to be with the line/package:

```
var PushNotification = require('react-native-push-notification');
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: i think u should try to use import instead of require

Comment: For example, I am using the "import" syntax, and I get the same error message.

Comment: I'm getting the same error but in Index.js:18:55 any solution?

Comment: Would be nice if they could tell us 'which modules'. Man I hate RN.

Answer (score 31):

The red-box complaints react-native cannot find some symbol `<unkown>` in `PushNotificationIOS.js line 18`.

This usually happens when you fail to link the third lib to your target causing NativeModules find nothing at attempt.

To solve this, your Project Navigator -> Target -> General -> Linked Frameworks and Libraries, make sure `somelib.a` is there.

[image]

In your case, please follow the [ios install guides](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification#ios-installation) and [react-native doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html#content)

Comment: or you may follow this link for complete linking libraries in RN, https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html

Answer (score 14):

Sometime, if you had another react-native packager already running for a different app. You may see this problem.

Especially if the react-native versions are same and the previously started app requires a native module which is not available in the current app.

In these cases, you can kill the react packager terminal and restart it and problem should go away.

Also if it is the same app and you just upgraded. Make sure that it is linked properly. If not call react-native link  again.

Answer (score 11):

In my case, running a `$ pod install` inside /ios directory did the trick!

Comment: If you are using React Native 0.60 and higher, this should solve your issue.

Comment: I think most people forget to install the pods and run into this issue. Upvoted.

Comment: been a long since this was posted but figured I would ask, how do you do this when you are using expo?

Answer (score 4):

remove react-native-push-notification in node_modules

run `npm install react-native-push-notification@3.1.3`

Answer (score 3):

I think this has to do with how to export and import your modules.
Make sure each corresponding

If you export your module like this `module.exports = moduleName;` You should import using  `var moduleName = require('moduleName');`

If export your module using `export default moduleName;`. You should import using `import ModuleName from './ModuleName;`

Review all your exports and imports.

Answer (score 3):

My issue had the same symptoms but a much different root cause. I had two React Native projects open in two different instances of Xcode. My Metro bundler was still running from Project A and causing problems running Project B in the simulator.

The fix: close the old terminal window spawned by Xcode that had the Metro Bundler running and re-run the project.

Comment: Very nice catch. Similar to a situation I just ran into: switched to new branch with a library swap, rebuilt the app, but didn't realize metro bundler was still running from before.

Answer (score 3):

1. `npm i @react-native-community/push-notification-ios`
2. `cd ios && pod install`
3. `react-native unlink @react-native-community/push-notification-ios`

That's how I solved it after struggling for hours.

Comment: God bless you 

Answer (score 1):

Please use react native community's ios push notification package instead of native's one.

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-push-notification-ios

Remove RCTPushNotification project from your libraries and try to use react-native-community's ios push notification. You need to follow the guide. (There are some differences in xcode and linking.)

Comment: Why? Is the other not being maintained? What about Android?

Answer (score 1):

1- In iOS message is 'Native module cannot be null'

2- In Android message is 'null is not an object evaluating RNFSManager etc'

Meaning is the same and solutions are different, for both cases you need to link native library manually.

Solution for iOS is run `pod install` in iOS Directory, then `react-native run-ios` to re-run the app.

Solution for android is `react-native link react-native-fs` then `react-native run-android` to re-run the app.

Note: In android better is to open project in android studio again to avoid any inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

if it helps someone.
Manual link the library in
node_modules/react-native/libraries/PushNotificationIOS/RCTPushNotification.xcodeproj for ios
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios#manual-linking

that's where the manual linking refers to. not react-native-push-notification

Answer (score 0):

Try command

```
$pod install
```

in `YourProject/ios`. It worked for me.

Hope it helps?