# React Native Ios: Native Module cannot be null

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Found Error in IOS

> Native Module cannot be null

#### I don't use `react-native-push-notification`

[image]

[image]

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38698657/react-native-native-module-cannot-be-null?rq=1 . It seems a duplicate question.

Comment: @Behzad, Can you please share your code?

Comment: have you resolved this??

Comment: @Behzad kahvand have you found solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens when you fail to link the third lib to your target causing NativeModules find nothing at attempt.

To solve this, go to `your Project Navigator -> Target -> General -> Linked Frameworks and Libraries`, make sure `somelib.a` is there.

[image]

In your case, please follow the [ios install guides](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification#ios-installation) and [react-native doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html#content)