# RN app result in "Native module cannot be null" after updating Expokit from 28 to 32

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, react-native-firebase

I am following the documents [expokit 32](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/expokit/#upgrading-expokit) [AppDelegate](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/expokit/expokit/#ios-1) to upgrade expo v28 to v32 and its detached branch.

I finally got everything working on my non-detached branch on my RN app. Now I am trying to upgrade the detached branch but the following error struck me.

[image: Erro Log from simulator]

Current set:
 - "react-native": sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz from expo 
 - "expo": "^32.0.0",
 - expo-cli --version 2.11.6
 - xcode 10.1
 - firebase 
 - "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0",
 - "react-native-firebase": "^5.0.0",
 - "aws-amplify": "^1.1.19",

The problem is that I don't even understand this error let alone how to handle it(there is nothing else print in the console from expo-cli). It points me to some files inside expo npm modules, ./node_modules/expo/tools/hashAssetFiles.js. which doesn`t make any sense to me :((

Maybe something wrong with my AppDelegate.m?

here is mine

```
// Copyright 2015-present 650 Industries. All rights reserved.

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Firebase.h"
#import "RNFirebaseNotifications.h"
#import "RNFirebaseMessaging.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

static NSString *const CUSTOM_URL_SCHEME = @"higuApp";

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    [FIRApp configure];
    [RNFirebaseNotifications configure];

    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
  [super applicationWillEnterForeground:application];
}

#pragma mark - Background Fetch

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
  [super application:application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}

#pragma mark - Handling URLs

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
  return [super application:app openURL:url options:options];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable))restorationHandler
{
  return [super application:application continueUserActivity:userActivity restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
}

#pragma mark - Notifications

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)token
{
  [super application:application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:token];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err
{
  [super application:application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:err];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{   
    [[RNFirebaseMessaging instance] didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler
{
    [[RNFirebaseNotifications instance] didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
  [super application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}

@end
```

Any suggestion is welcomed.

- I have tried to comment out everything in App.js and return just null, but the problem persists.
- Google lead me to some similar cases which are caused by [push notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38698657/react-native-native-module-cannot-be-null), but that doesnt see to be my problem.
  I tried comment out the codes in AppDelegate.m and doesnt help with the situation.

Comment: Have you edited any native code in your project?

Comment: @10101010 only the AppDelegate.m and .h file when upgrading I believe.