# How do you send push/local notifications ? My code fails :(

Tags: react-native, push-notification

I can't create an app that sends local push notifications :( WHY ??

https://apiko.com/blog/react-native-push-notifications/

I did like every step of this tutorial but still ain't working!

Native module cannot be null

Comment: add code and error in detail

Comment: also refr.. https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/160

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38698657/react-native-native-module-cannot-be-null3