# Getting "Unhandled JS Exception: Native module cannot be null" Error on IOS runtime with React Native

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

Preparing a medium size production level app 
for IOS.

App uses a lot of native capabilities and and some point of attempting 
to integrate some of them I moved to using [Cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/).
manually using a `Podfile` file.

This helped me to over come all the build fails and could finally get the RN app running.

Only now, getting a very vague error:

```
Unhandled JS Exception: Native module cannot be null
```

Having a hard time to figure out which 3rd party package is causing this..
a bunch of `git` issues are pointing to add the right package to `Podfile` file 
and `pod install` which I did, but still not joy.

Those are the `git issues, most of them in a specific package:

- [SO answers for 'react-native-push-notification'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38698657/react-native-native-module-cannot-be-null)
- [Git issue in 'react-native-tab-view'](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view/issues/711)
- [Git issue in 'react-native-push-notification'](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/160)
- [Git issue in '
  react-native-vector-icons'](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/972)
- [Git issue solution](https://github.com/react-native-community/push-notification-ios/issues/43#issuecomment-575655353)

Most of those pretty much solve this the same way by adding to `Podfile` file the right pod link and running `pod install` - this did not worked for me

Things that I've tried:

- Removing binary links but `JavaScriptCore.framework` and `libPods-myProjectName.a`
- Clearing `Libraries` from all `.xcodeproj` packages to resolve duplicated linking
- Cleaned project rebuilt, cleared packages with `pod deintegrate` and reinstalled.. basically cleared and reinstalled everything I could
- Upgrade `react-native` from `0.58.6` to `0.59.9`

Followed [this blog post](https://engineering.brigad.co/demystifying-react-native-modules-linking-ae6c017a6b4a) to convert my existing project to use [Cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/)`

Pod install seems pass without any errors - `pod install` output:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
Downloading dependencies
Installing AppAuth (1.3.0)
Installing BugsnagReactNative (2.23.1)
Installing DoubleConversion (1.1.6)
Installing Folly (2018.10.22.00)
Installing RNDeviceInfo (2.3.2)
Installing RNGestureHandler (1.1.0)
Installing RNSVG (9.5.1)
Installing RNShare (3.0.0)
Installing RNSound (0.11.0)
Installing RNVectorIcons (6.6.0)
Installing React (0.59.9)
Installing ReactNativePermissions (1.1.1)
Installing boost-for-react-native (1.63.0)
Installing glog (0.3.5)
Installing react-native-camera (2.1.1)
Installing react-native-image-picker (0.28.1)
Installing react-native-image-resizer (1.2.0)
Installing react-native-keep-awake (4.0.0)
Installing react-native-netinfo (3.2.1)
Installing react-native-orientation (3.1.3)
Installing react-native-view-shot (3.1.2)
Installing react-native-webview (5.7.0)
Installing yoga (0.59.9.React)
Installing ReactNativeNFC (1.0.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Pod installation complete! There are 31 dependencies from the Podfile and 23 total pods installed.
```

And the `Podfile`:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'myProjectName' do
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'Core',
    'CxxBridge',
    'DevSupport',
    'RCTText',
    'RCTImage',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTWebSocket',
    'RCTSettings',
    'RCTAnimation',
    'RCTLinkingIOS',
    # Add any other subspecs you want to use in your project
    # Remove any subspecs you don't want to use in your project
  ]

  pod "yoga", :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga"
  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'
  pod 'react-native-webview', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-webview'
  pod 'RNSound', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-sound'
  pod 'react-native-camera', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-camera'
  pod 'RNDeviceInfo', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-device-info'
  pod 'RNGestureHandler', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler'
  pod 'react-native-image-picker', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-image-picker'
  pod 'react-native-image-resizer', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-image-resizer'
  pod 'react-native-keep-awake', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-keep-awake'
  pod 'react-native-orientation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-orientation'

  # permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'
  # pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera.podspec"

  pod 'ReactNativePermissions', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-permissions'
  pod 'RNShare', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-share'
  pod 'RNSVG', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-svg'
  pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'
  pod 'react-native-view-shot', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-view-shot'
  pod 'AppAuth'
  pod 'BugsnagReactNative', :path => '../node_modules/bugsnag-react-native'
  pod 'react-native-netinfo', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/netinfo'
  pod 'ReactNativeNFC', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-rfid-nfc-scanner/ios'

end
```

And my `dependancies` inside `package.json`:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "3.2.1",
    "axios": "0.18.0",
    "bugsnag-react-native": "2.23.1",
    "country-list": "2.1.1",
    "formik": "1.5.1",
    "link": "^0.1.5",
    "moment": "2.24.0",
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.9",
    "react-native-android-location-enabler": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-android-wifi": "0.0.41",
    "react-native-app-auth": "^4.4.0",
    "react-native-camera": "2.1.1",
    "react-native-collapsible": "1.4.0",
    "react-native-country-picker-modal": "0.7.1",
    "react-native-device-info": "2.3.2",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.16.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "1.1.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "0.28.1",
    "react-native-image-resizer": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-keep-awake": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "2.5.4",
    "react-native-orientation": "3.1.3",
    "react-native-permissions": "1.1.1",
    "react-native-pinch-zoom-responder": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "1.1.2",
    "react-native-rfid-nfc-scanner": "github:avshalomp/react-native-rfid-nfc#fix/nfc_infrastructure",
    "react-native-share": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-smooth-pincode-input": "1.0.3",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-status-bar-height": "2.3.1",
    "react-native-svg": "9.5.1",
    "react-native-svg-charts": "5.2.0",
    "react-native-swipe-gestures": "1.0.3",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.14",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "6.6.0",
    "react-native-view-shot": "^3.1.2",
    "react-native-webview": "^5.7.0",
    "react-native-wifi": "1.0.1",
    "react-navigation": "3.3.2",
    "react-navigation-transitions": "1.0.10",
    "react-redux": "6.0.1",
    "redux": "4.0.1",
    "redux-persist": "5.10.0",
    "redux-saga": "1.0.2",
    "reselect": "4.0.0",
    "styled-components": "4.1.3",
    "yup": "0.26.10"
  }
```

My current env:

```
   React: 16.6.3,
   React Native: 0.59.9 // tested with React Native 0.58.6 too
   Xcode: 11.4.1
```

Really having hard time to debug this one as React Native errors are not so helpful, plus probably missing something

Any Ideas how to get more info about this one?

Or how to solve it?

Help..

Comment: When you say Profile you mean Podfile? To do pod install, you need a Podfile.

Comment: yes, sorry. was a bit in a hurry when uploaded this, plus still kinda new to IOS native stuff - edited it

Comment: No problem! which message pod install shows after installing?

Comment: its too long for the comments Iv'e added all the output of `pod install` to the main post

Comment: Thanks for that! Your podfile and pod install seems ok! Now show me your package.json. I think that some module isn't linked yet.

Comment: added the dependancies in the package.json file.. went one by one.. just added `react-native-rfid-nfc-scanner` and still same result

Comment: I added one answer to track new missing packages to install. Let's try to install each one.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your Podfile:

```
pod 'ReactNativeNFC', :path => "../node_modules/react-native-rfid-nfc/ios"
```

then:

```
pod install
```

If i find a new un-installed component, i'll add here.

Comment: thanks, I just added it and installed still the same error. BTW, the `.podspec` file is inside the `ios` folder so the path is `"../node_modules/react-native-rfid-nfc/ios"`

Comment: You're right. I edited the answer. So, did you add react-native-wifi into Podfile? I can't see.

Comment: Tested it in the code, but now updated here and added the whole `Podfile` too.. it really starts to be an over content SO post :/

Comment: Yes, i just tried to give you a direction. Now, i think that some minutes investigating, you can find the missing dependencies to insert on Podfile. =)

Comment: thanks, although I went one by one.. added all of them still the same.. Im sure its something super small and silly iv'e missed.. thanks for you patience either way - highly appreciated :)